# django-cms apphook urls don't work with reverse() using Python shell

Tags: python, django, shell, django-cms

I've created a django CMS apphook. Unfortunately I'm not able to reverse apphook urls using the Python shell.

The `cms_app.py` file looks like:

```
class ArticleApp (CMSApp):
    name = _('Article App')
    app_name = 'article_app'
    urls = ['article.urls']

apphook_pool.register(ArticleApp)
```

This is my `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)?', ArticleView.as_view(), name='article-by-slug'),
)
```

The template file is:

```
{% url 'article_app:article-by-slug' article.slug %}
```

URL reversing inside the template performs like expected. If I try to do the same using the Python shell I receive an error message:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> from article.models import Article
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> reverse('article_app:article-by-slug', kwargs={'slug': a.slug})
# Reverse for 'article_app:article-by-slug' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'this-is-article-1'}' not found.
```

Additional urls defined in the main `urls.py` work like expected from inside the shell. Only apphook urls don't work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Benjamin Wohlwend I was able to solve the problem. The apphook page wasn't available in the "en-us" language (the default for Django management commands like "shell"). I had to activate the correct language before reversing:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('de')
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right anwser. Saved time for me!

Answer (score 0):

remove the namespace from the reverse:

```
reverse('article-by-slug', kwargs={'slug': a.slug})
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. Neither if I remove the app_name from the `cms_app.py` file.